# Pyparsing: nested Markdown emphasis

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm noodling around with some simple Markdown text to play with and learn Pyparsing and grammars in general.  I've run into a problem almost immediately that I'm having trouble solving.  I'm trying to parse a simple version of the [CommonMark](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis) spec for emphasis.  In this setup, nested emphasis is allowed, so that

```
*foo *bar* baz*
```

should give:

```
<em>foo <em>bar</em> baz</em>
```

I've tried using a recursive definition to match this, but it's not working.  Here's some sample code:

```
from pyparsing import *

text = Word(printables,excludeChars="*")
enclosed = Forward()
emphasis = QuotedString("*").setParseAction(lambda x: "<em>%s</em>" % x[0],contents=enclosed)
enclosed << emphasis | text

test = """
*foo *bar* bar*
"""

print emphasis.transformString(test)
```

But what I get back from this is:

```
<em>foo </em>bar<em> bar</em>
```

Forgive my noobishness;  can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**:

In response to abarnert's great probing question, I'll provide clarification.  I'm just playing around, so I can use an arbitrarily restricted form of the notation. I'll assume that only single '*'s occur, and that they don't occur next to each other.  That leaves the whitespace to disambiguate:  * not followed by whitespace opens emphasis, and * not preceeded by whitespace closes it.

Even with that, I'm not sure how to proceed with Pyparsing.  Some sort of stack-based approach, pushing opening * and popping them when they validate as closing? How would one do that with Pyparsing?  Or is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do the version you want is to drop the automatic whitespace processing and treat whitespace as a token… but I'm not sure. I'll let my subconscious mull over it, and if you're still stuck and nobody else gets back to you, I'll take a whack at it later.

Comment: As soon as you say something like "treat whitespace as a token," I think pyparsing starts to be not the best choice. Implicit whitespace-skipping is a key part of its charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those additional rules, I don't think you need to worry about the recursion at all, just handle the opening and closing emphasis expressions as they are found, whether they match up or not:

```
from pyparsing import *

openEmphasis = (LineStart() | White()) + Suppress('*')
openEmphasis.setParseAction(lambda x: ''.join(x.asList()+['<em>']))
closeEmphasis = '*' + FollowedBy(White() | LineEnd())
closeEmphasis.setParseAction(lambda x: '</em>')

emphasis = (openEmphasis | closeEmphasis).leaveWhitespace()

test = """
*foo *bar* bar*
"""
print test
print emphasis.transformString(test)
```

Prints:

```
*foo *bar* bar*

<em>foo <em>bar</em> bar</em>
```

You are not the first to trip over this kind of application. When I presented at PyCon'06, an eager attendee dove right in to parse out some markdown, with an input string something like `"****a** b**** c**"` or something. We worked on it a bit together, but the disambiguation rules were just too context-aware for a basic pyparsing parser to handle.

Comment: Thanks so much, Paul! I admire how much help you give people with Pyparsing.  For curiosity's sake, do you think Pyparsing could produce a full parser for Commonmark?  (I wasn't planning on trying it, just trying to get my feet wet with the library and grammars in general, but it leaves me wondering if it's possible).

Comment: Skipping the recursion means that if given broken Markdown he'll successfully generate broken HTML, instead of failing, right? (I don't think this is a problem—he never asked to write a validating parser or generate a tree with emphasis nodes or anything—I just want to to clarify it.)

Comment: @Winawer: It sounds looks like it should be doable if you follow the [parsing strategy](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#appendix-a-a-parsing-strategy)—that is, a first pass to build a tree, followed by a tree walk. In a few sections the spec refers to things being parseable without backtracking, which sounds like they made sure they were designing an LL(k) language (you wouldn't talk about backtracking unless you were distinguishing predictive vs. backtracking recursive descent, right?).

Comment: A quick glance at the spec reveals pyparsing's nemesis: significant leading whitespace (used to identify code blocks). Pyparsing works better with applications that handle the input text as a continuous stream, or a succession of separate lines.

Comment: @abarnert - yes, bad markdown will create bad HTML with this approach. Many pyparsing apps that I've seen make this assumption, that the input has already been validated separately, and that the pyparsing app is extracting some pieces of interest. I'm doing this now with a big chunk of Groovy code - I know that it is syntactically correct, so I can just sift through for class definitions, etc. without having to worry about erroneous syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Actually, the parsing strategy section specifically recommends parsing it as a succession of separate lines. However, you do seem to need to keep track of the indentation context in order to handle many of the productions (and list items look more problematical than code blocks). Obviously you know better than I whether that's doable.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you're asking for. When does a second `*` close emphasis, and when does it open a nested emphasis? You have written no rules to distinguish that. Since it's always 100% ambiguous, that means the only possible outcomes you can get are:

- No emphasis can ever be closed, or
- No emphasis can ever be nested.

I doubt you're asking how to switch from the second to the first.

So then what *are* you asking for?

You need to implement some kind of rule to disambiguate these two possibilities.

In fact, if you read the docs you linked to, they have a complicated set of rules that define exactly when a `*` can open emphasis and when it can't, and likewise for closng; given those rules, if it's still ambiguous, it closes emphasis. You have to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for the push to clarify my thinking.  I hope that my edit to the question helps.

Comment: Excellent comment. This sort of thing is why I encourage people to think through the grammar a bit (usually by writing up a rough BNF) before jumping right into the "writing the parser" part.