# Pyparsing nested transformString

Tags: python, pyparsing

I had something working for a little while to transform a tag from `lua` to `hmtl`, but recently I got a special case where those tags could be nested. Here is a quick sample out of my code :

```py
from pyparsing import Literal, Word, Suppress, SkipTo, LineEnd, hexnums

text = "|c71d5FFFFI'm saying something in color|cFFFFFFFF then in white |r|r"

def colorize (t):
    hexRGB = "".join(list(t.hex)[:6])
    return "<span style=\"color:#{};\">{}</span>".format(hexRGB, t.content)

vbar = Literal("|")
eol = LineEnd().suppress()

endTag = ((vbar + (Literal("r")|Literal("R"))|eol))
parser = (
    Suppress(vbar + (Literal("c")|Literal("C"))) + 
    Word(hexnums, exact=8).setResultsName("hex") + 
    SkipTo(endTag).setResultsName("content") + 
    Suppress(endTag)
).addParseAction(colorize)

result = parser.transformString(text)
print (result)
```

I saw an another similar question [Pyparsing: nested Markdown emphasis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780553/pyparsing-nested-markdown-emphasis), but my problem is a bit different, sometime there is no closetag and lineEnd is acting as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `while` loop to iterate over result until all the colors are found:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, Word, Suppress, SkipTo, LineEnd, hexnums


def colorize (t):
    hexRGB = "".join(list(t.hex)[:6])
    return "<span style=\"color:#{};\">{}</span>".format(hexRGB, t.content)

vbar = Literal("|")
eol = LineEnd().suppress()

endTag = ((vbar + (Literal("r")|Literal("R"))|eol))
parser = (
    Suppress(vbar + (Literal("c")|Literal("C"))) + 
    Word(hexnums, exact=8).setResultsName("hex") + 
    SkipTo(endTag).setResultsName("content") + 
    Suppress(endTag)
).addParseAction(colorize)

result = parser.transformString(text)
new_result = parser.transformString(result)

while(result != new_result):
   result = new_result
   new_result = parser.transformString(result)


print (result)
```

when `text = "|c71d5FFFFI'm saying something in color|cFFFFFFFF then in white |r|r"`:

output:

```
<span style="color:#71d5FF;">I'm saying something in color<span style="color:#FFFFFF;"> then in white</span></span>
```

when `text = "|c71d5FFFFI'm saying something in color"`

output:

```
<span style="color:#71d5FF;">I'm saying something in color</span>
```